# Scheme passing null list as function paramater

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm doing some basic lisp/scheme and I am running into the problem where I can't pass an empty list/null (it is my understanding they behave almost identically) into a function.
For example:

```
(define (fxn L) 
  (if (null? L)
      ( '() ) 
      (cdr L)))
```

And I am getting

```
> (fxn '())
procedure application: expected procedure, given: () (no arguments)

> (fxn null)
procedure application: expected procedure, given: () (no arguments)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have parentheses around `'()` in your if statement.
`'()` is a literal not a function, therefore you can't call it, i.e, surround it in parentheses.

Try:

```
(define (fxn L)
  (if (null? L)
      '()
      (cdr L)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it